# Attach multiple Fingerprint scanners to one computer

Tags: .net, windows, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm working on building a solution which can capture input from multiple fingerprint readers simultaneously.

So far we have tried using the UPEK EikonTouch 710 which only supports one scanner per computer (at the driver level).

What scanners would you recommend? We are trying to stick to a .net solution so something with windows drivers is definitely preferred.